# Appcenter does not show any apps?

Tags: appcenter, error

When I start Appcenter, I see that I can't install new apps in 6.1 version.
[image: For example, in "Graphics" section I just se "Photos" app]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install an app from flathub and then reopen appcenter if this does not work I do not know what you can do